# wakanda remove() Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined - errCode 4055

Tags: wakanda

I do the tuto wakanda at new version and I have error code 4055 when I play js a method addSuperheroes.js. 
Please I need help.

Method:

```
ds.Superhero.remove();
new ds.Superhero({name:"Batman"}).save();
new ds.Superhero({name:"Superman"}).save();
var favoriteSuperhero = new ds.Superhero({name:"Wonder Woman"});
favoriteSuperhero.save();
ds.Superhero.all();
```

Error:

```
{
    "__ERROR": [
        {
            "message": "Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined, line #1, file:///Users/arnaudthierard/Documents/Wakanda/solutions/HelloWorldWeb/back-end-superheroes/script/addSuperheroes.js.",
            "componentSignature": "jvsc",
            "errCode": 4055
        },
        {
            "message": "Error evaluating javascript file:///Users/arnaudthierard/Documents/Wakanda/solutions/HelloWorldWeb/back-end-superheroes/script/addSuperheroes.js",
            "componentSignature": "JS4D",
            "errCode": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Superhero class is defined? Have you tried reloading the solution / server before running the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the dataclass in the model is named *Superhero*.( not *superhero* or *SuperHero* ... )

Comment: I have write "Superhero" : "classes": {
   "Superhero": {
    "panelColor": "#B7DDE8",
    "panel": {
     "isOpen": "true",
     "pathVisible": true,
     "position": {
      "X": 25,
      "Y": 20
     }
    }
   },
   "Movie": {
    "panelColor": "#E5B9B7",
    "panel": {
     "isOpen": "true",
     "pathVisible": true,
     "position": {
      "X": 349,
      "Y": 21
     }
    }
   }
  },

Comment: Anyone can help me ?

Comment: This same example worked for me, here is a screencast of what i have tried https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1UZlfLCde0zSkc0T19kNHlja2c/view?usp=sharing
i hope it will help

Comment: @Pratoux Can you tag the right answer to help others with the same issue ?